# Why are the data not being shown in tree form?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 4 app with 2 modules:`menu` and `app` . The menu module shows some data in tree form. I've used the `angular2-tree` library for that.

This is my `MenuComponent`:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
TreeComponent,
TreeNode,
} from 'angular-tree-component';



@Component({
selector: 'menu',
templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent  {

constructor() { }


nodes = [
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'root1',
  children: [
    { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
    { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
  ]
},
{
  id: 4,
  name: 'root2',
  children: [
    { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'child2.2',
      children: [
        { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
       ]
      }
    ]
}
]
}
```

And this is the html for this component:

```
 <div class="Tree">
 <tree-root [nodes]="nodes">
 <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node let-index="index">
 <a><span>{{ node.data.id }}</span></a>
 </ng-template>
 </tree-root>
 </div>
```

I wanted to test this component in my `AppComponent` and so I called the menu using its selector:

```
<menu></menu>
```

Instead of getting the data in tree form, I only get the elements with id 1 and 4 but none of their children. No idea why this happens.

The weird thing is , if I use `<router-outlet>` it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to iterate over this "children" attribute from the 'nodes' object.
There is nothing in your code that do this.

Comment: No, I don't have to do that. The `angular2-tree` library is supposed to take care of that.